# How does extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long> work

Tags: android, android-asynctask, extends

I would like to know how it works. I have read the documentation a couple of times but don’t get the idea.

I noticed that in some cases `onPostExecute` does nothing.

Can anyone please give me a little explanation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`AsyncTask` is a class derived from `Thread` and provides you a simple and proper way of doing some things in the background with the ability of notifying the `UI Thread`.

In order to use it you should create a `class`, which `extends` it and define the type parameters. They are `Params`, `Progress` and `Result`. Read about them more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

`onPostExecute()` is a method which is called when `doInBackground()` finished it's execution, but `onPostExecute()` is run on the UI Thread. So, you can notify the UI about the work has been done.

You can see an example of `AsyncTask` usage [here](http://www.lidsoft.ru/?p=150&lang=en).

Answer (score 3):

The `<Void, Void, Long>` part is what in Java is called [Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). It is used in those classes where the original coder wants it to be used no matter what the types the "end user" will choose.

Typically you use `onPre/PostExecute()` when you want to start/stop a progress dialog.

If you want to update the UI during the progress without a progress dialog you can do things in `onProgressUpdate()` (i.e.: you're loading images from web and displaying them as they get loaded)

If you have a dialog with progress bar you'll have to use all of them to update the progress bar.

Comment: Yup, but I have noticed, that if you do Void, Void, Void, onPostExecute does nothing...

Comment: @M.V.: that method takes as an argument what is returned by `doInBackground()`. The last `Void` says you're not returning a value (which is legitimate), so `onPostExecute()` will take no arguments. You could still stop an indeterminate progress dialog there, though.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructs-part-3.html) post explains AsyncTask concept nicely with diagram !

Answer (score 0):

`{onPostExecute()}` is used when you want to do something after completing your background   task `{(doInBackground())}`.

For example,

```
start Progress Bar @ {onPreExecute()}
running Progress Bar @ {doInBackground()}
stop Progress Bar @ {onPostExecute()}
```